# I don't know why create_app is called in every test function

Tags: flask, flask-testing

I write testing code using flask_testing

following is my testing code

```
from app import create_app, db

class SampleTest(TestCase):
    def create_app(self):
        self.db_fd, self.db_path = tempflie.mkstemp()
        return create_app({'DATABASE': self.db_path})

    def setUp(self):
        db.create_all()

    def tearDown(self):
        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()
        os.close(self.db_fd)
        os.unlink(self.db_path)

    def test1(self):
        response = self.get('/test1/')

    def test2(self):
        response = self.get('/test2/')
```

when I debug the test code, I found that create_app is called in all test functions, including test1, test.

how can i call create_app function only once?

Answer (score 0):

```
def create_app(self):
    self.db_fd, self.db_path = tempflie.mkstemp()
    return create_app({'DATABASE': self.db_path})
```

This is confusing and I suspect not intended you import create_app and have a method called create_app.

Also do you have a @pytest.fixture on your imported create_app?